# MySQL question for conversation app

Tags: mysql, database

I have an app that manages conversations between users on a website. It does one to one conversations as well as having multiple people in a single conversation.

Here is the layout for the mysql tables

conversations
conversations_meta

The conversations_meta table links users to the conversations by logging user_id and conversation_id. It also holds meta info about the conversation specific to each user in the conversation.

What I am having trouble with is detecting if a conversation with the same people already exist.
For example if a conversation between Eric Jason and bob exists but maybe it's old and the user forgot about it and then tries to create an addition conversation with the same users I would like to notify them of the conversation.

So the query should look in conversations_meta table and compare user_id and conversation_id to see if the same conversation exists already. Also I wouldn't want it to return conversations that include all the same users and additional users as well.
The main reason I posted this question on here is to get the fastest query possible to accomplish this task since there will be thousands of conversations.

Comment: do the two tables that have "_messages" in their name have any bearing?

Comment: Not in this query. I will edit that out

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
SELECT conversations_meta.conversations_id FROM conversations_meta  
where (conversations_meta.user_id=1) or (conversations_meta.user_id=2)
group by conversations_id HAVING count(*) = 2
```

**NOTE**: this is a case for only 2 people in the conversation.  Easily expanded to the case of 3 or or more.

Comment: it almost works. But for some reason if there is a third person in the conversation it still returns the conversation_id. The count(*) = 2 isn't restricting it to only 2